# Mysql - Remove text from INT type column

Tags: mysql, double, varchar

i am doing a migration

i have a column name `amount_in_rmb` `VARCHAR`. but i want to change it to `DOUBLE(10,2)`.

The problem is, some rows of `amount_in_rmb` contain data like `RMB1525`, `RM23523` and etc

I want only the `1525` but dont want the `RMB` because i am changing the column type to double

my question is, how to use mysql query or any method to remove the "RMB" or "RM" from the rows ? The numeric value is very important and it must not be deleted.

Comment: if only RMB your not numeric info, use a REPLACE function in this way: REPLACE(field, 'RMB', '')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are the only possible prefixes, you can do:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET amount_in_rmb = CASE WHEN amount_in_rmb LIKE 'RMB%' THEN SUBSTR(amount_in_rmb, 4)
                         WHEN amount_in_rmb LIKE 'RM%' THEN SUBSTR(amount_in_rmb, 3)
                         ELSE amount_in_rmb
                    END
```

If there are other prefixes, add more `WHEN` clauses. I don't think there's an easy way to skip over all letters at the beginning with SQL.

Comment: thanks barmar. there are few more possible prefixes actually. what i did is squeeze in a few more WHEN-LIKE-THEN to make it done. by the way, if you have better solution that work for more possible prefixes i believe it will help someone else looking for such solution :)